# How check if a list contains value or key inside a another list in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How can I check if a list contains a key or value inside a sublist (of sublist ..) or in the "root"
And is possible to get a the "path"?

This containsValue or containsKey seems only to look in the root of the list

Example pseudo:

```
//This is my list
list = [languages:[_clazz:"basics.i18n.Language", messages:[_clazz:"basics.i18n.Message"]]] 

list.containsKey("languages") // return true
list.containsValue("basics.i18n.Language") // return false where I want true
list.containsKey("messages") // return false // return false where I want true
list.containsValue("basics.i18n.Message") // return false where I want true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in Groovy for this I don't think, but you can write your own and add them to `Map` (what you have is a `Map`, not a `List` as you have named the variable)

```
Map.metaClass.deepContainsKey = { value ->
    delegate.containsKey(value) ?:
    delegate.values().findAll { it instanceof Map }.findResult { it.deepContainsKey(value) } ?:
    false
}

Map.metaClass.deepContainsValue = { value ->
    delegate.containsValue(value) ?:
    delegate.values().findAll { it instanceof Map }.findResult { it.deepContainsValue(value) } ?:
    false
}
```

Then, given your map:

```
def map = [languages:[_clazz:"basics.i18n.Language", messages:[_clazz:"basics.i18n.Message"]]]
```

All of these assertions pass:

```
assert map.deepContainsKey("messages") 
assert map.deepContainsValue("basics.i18n.Message")
assert map.deepContainsValue("basics.i18n.Language")

assert !map.deepContainsKey("missing") 
assert !map.deepContainsValue("novalue")
```

Comment: A trivial thing but I think you could probably replace `.findResult` with `.any` since you don't really need the return value.  If you did that you could also eliminate the `?: false` from the end of those calls since the return value from `.any` would yield the same result with less work.